# Friction on a cycle tire while turning

Tags: forces, friction, torque

I was searching for a satisfactory answer on this topic but was unable to find an aggregated almost accurate explanation to this or perhaps I am still not able to get physics. Anyways I have thought of a probable explanation about this by acquiring notions from many sources. I just need a bit verification about this. So would like to request anyone who has seen this question to atleast comment out whether the explanation is right or not.

[image: Two images of probable condition of the tire and road interaction]

Let us start with the left image. In this image the path AB seems to be in contact with the surface. Between their interaction a normal force is acting on the tire(blue colored). And another force which is not seen in the image is the weight. This two forces are unlike parallel forces and give rise to a torque. So due to this torque the cycle is supposed to rotate.

On the right image we see that the length of patch AB is tending to reduce due to torque, so the tire apples a tangential force on the road surface. But due to friction, net force turns out to be zero. And this could be te reason for which cycle gains centripetal force and thus rotates.

So my question is: is this explanation/notion correct?

Please do tell me where I have made wrong while understanding this concept.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish there were any option for questioning anonymously. Asking this type of questions is too embarassing.

Comment: If you would like to be more anonymous, you can always change the displayed name from your user profile.

Comment: "This two forces are unlike parallel forces and give rise to a torque".  What makes you think the upward reaction force (normal force) does not equal the downward weight?

Comment: Their point of action are not the same. So even if it equals the weight it won't be able to negate its effect completely as far as I know